# Insert \searrow between cells in an table with white background

Tags: tables, arrows, cell

I am preparing a text in which the student can learn alternative fast way to find a solution of an integral. So, in the below, I made a MWE of illustrating the way by manipulating the codes. Sorry if it seems ugly to you!

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}‎
 ‎\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}‎
 ‎\usepackage{mathrsfs,mathtools}
‎‎ ‎\usepackage{float}‎ 
 ‎\usepackage{xcolor}‎ 
 \usepackage{extarrows}‎‎‎ 
 ‎\usepackage{array}‎ 
 \begin{document}
 ‎‎\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc} 
 $\boxed{t^3}‎$‎ ‎‎ & | ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎& ‎$‎3t^2‎$ ‎ ‎& | & ‎$‎6t‎$ &|& ‎$‎6‎$ ‎&|& ‎0‎\\‎‎‎[-0.2em]
 ‎‎‎& ‎$‎‎\searrow$‎‎ & & $‎‎\searrow$ & & ‎$‎‎\searrow$ & & $‎‎\searrow$ &‎‎‎‎\\‎[-0.6em]
 ‎‎\hline\\‎‎‎[-1em]
 $e^{2t}$ ‎‎‎& |‎ & ‎$\boxed{e^{2t}/2}‎‎$‎ & | & ‎$‎e^{2t}/4‎$ ‎&|& ‎‎$‎e^{2t}/8‎$ &|& ‎$‎e^{2t}/16‎$‎‎‎\\‎[0.8em]
& ‎‎ & $‎‎‎\downarrow‎$ & & $‎‎‎\downarrow‎$& & $‎‎‎\downarrow‎$ & & $‎‎‎\downarrow‎$\\‎‎[0.8em]
& & ‎‎‎‎$‎\dfrac{t^3e^{2t}}{2}$ &‎ & ‎‎‎‎$‎\dfrac{3t^2e^{2t}}{4}‎‎$ &‎ &‎ ‎‎$‎\dfrac{6te^{2t}} 
{8}‎$ ‎&&‎ $‎\dfrac{6e^{2t}}{16}‎‎$
\end{tabular}‎‎‎‎
\end{document}
```

[image]

May I ask you how could I insert that `\searrow` with the white bacground as you see below:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\colorbox{white}{....}` gives you a white background.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs,mathtools}
 \usepackage{float} 
 \usepackage{xcolor} 
 \usepackage{extarrows} 
 \usepackage{array} 
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc} 
 $\boxed{t^3}$  & | & $3t^2$  & | & $6t$ &|& $6$ &|& 0\\[0.4em]
 \hline\\[-1.8em]
 & \colorbox{white}{$\searrow$} & & \colorbox{white}{$\searrow$} & & \colorbox{white}{$\searrow$} & & \colorbox{white}{$\searrow$} &\\[-0.2em]
 $e^{2t}$ & | & $\boxed{e^{2t}/2}$ & | & $e^{2t}/4$ &|& $e^{2t}/8$ &|& $e^{2t}/16$\\[0.8em]
&  & $\downarrow$ & & $\downarrow$& & $\downarrow$ & & $\downarrow$\\[0.8em]
& & $\dfrac{t^3e^{2t}}{2}$ & & $\dfrac{3t^2e^{2t}}{4}$ & & $\dfrac{6te^{2t}} 
{8}$ && $\dfrac{6e^{2t}}{16}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another version (not that I would do any of this in my documents, I would probably use `tikzmark` if I really decided to add such arrows).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,amsfonts}
 \usepackage{mathrsfs,mathtools}
 \usepackage{float} 
 \usepackage{xcolor} 
 \usepackage{extarrows} 
 \usepackage{array} 
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c|}c} 
 $\boxed{t^3}$  &  $3t^2$  & $6t$ & $6$ & 0\\[0.4em]
 \hline\\[-1.8em]
 \multicolumn{5}{l}{\hphantom{$\boxed{t^3}$}\hspace*{-0.1em}\colorbox{white}{$\searrow$}%  
 \hphantom{$\boxed{e^{2t}/2}$}\hspace*{-0.4em}\colorbox{white}{$\searrow$}%  
 \hphantom{$e^{2t}/4$}\hspace*{-0.1em}\colorbox{white}{$\searrow$}%
 \hphantom{$e^{2t}/8$}\hspace*{-0.4em}\colorbox{white}{$\searrow$}} \\[-0.2em]
 $e^{2t}$  & $\boxed{e^{2t}/2}$ &  $e^{2t}/4$ & $e^{2t}/8$ & $e^{2t}/16$\\[0.8em]
&  $\downarrow$ &  $\downarrow$&  $\downarrow$ &  $\downarrow$\\[0.8em]
&  $\dfrac{t^3e^{2t}}{2}$ &  $\dfrac{3t^2e^{2t}}{4}$ &  $\dfrac{6te^{2t}} 
{8}$ & $\dfrac{6e^{2t}}{16}$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the time. I did your hint but it did not make a change. I replaced the `white` by `green` and I did it worked nicely. May I ask you why I didn't get your figure when I used `white`? I am using the latest version of LATEX.

Comment: @mrs My screen shot was produced by compiling the above code with `pdflatex` on an updated TeXLive LaTeX installation.

Comment: Oh! My heart is to stopped. How nicely it looks. Thanks for your time and regrds.